# Problema subiendo archivo a FTP con Wininet

Tags: c++, windows, ftp, gcc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Copié este código de una respuesta en inglés pero al compilarlo arroja un montón de errores
Estoy usando Windows 7 de 32 bits y GCC 10.3.0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <wininet.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet")

int main() {
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, "servidor", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "usuario", "contraseña", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0);
    FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, "D:\\test.txt", "\\test.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
    std::cout << "File Uploaded." << std::endl;
    InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
    return 0;
}
```